# Wildcard with super

Tags: java, wildcard

Consider

```
List<? super Integer> lst= new ArrayList<Number>();
lst.add(new Integer(3)); //ok- why?? I expected compile error "expected add(int, Object), found add(int,CAP#1)"
lst.get(0); //ok
```

and

```
List <? extends Number> nums= new ArrayList<Integer>();
lst.add(new Integer(3));//Compile error- expected add(int, Object), found add(int,CAP#1)
```

On the compile state we dont know about type of `<? extends Number>` and have compile error. Does we know about type of `<? super Integer>` on compile state? Why?

Answer (score 2):

Of course - you know that whatever the value of the wildcard is, it is a superclass of `Integer` (by definition, from the bounds).  So no matter what its concrete class is, you have a list of something that can hold an `Integer`.  A `List<Object>` or `List<Number>` works just as well as a `List<Integer>` in this context.

With *extends* however, it's a different story.  A `List<? extends Number>` could be a `List<Double>`, so it's clear that an Integer cannot be inserted into this list without violating type-safety.  (In fact, nothing at all can be inserted - apart from `null` - for this reason.)

Comment: OK, thanks. Now i dont understand what differents `List<? super Integer> lst = new ArrayList<Number>();` from `List<Number> lst = new ArrayList<Number>();`?

Comment: @St.Antario Both of those lines involve two things.  *First*, you define a variable called `lst`, and say what type it is.  *Then*, you construct an object and assign it to this variable.  The actual type of the object, and the declared type of the variable, can be different.  Compare `Object a = "hello";` vs `String b = "hello";`, if that helps.  The actual string is the same in both cases, but you can't call `a.length()` because the only guarantee you have of what's in `a` is that it's an `Object`.